# Computing optimal price for data plan

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I am having problem with this algorithm question:

> A data plan has a cost of X. We are given an array of (unsorted)
>   integers, Y (1 <= Y <= 1e6). For each integer Y, if Y > X, then total
>   cost is incremented by X + (Y - X) * (Y - X). Otherwise, total cost is
>   incremented by X. Please find a value of X so that the total cost is
>   minimized.

On first thought, a `O(N^2)` method is trivial and easy to code but it will be very inefficient for a large input array (i.e. 2e5) .

My approach is to use binary search. As a precursor, I sort the array. Then I imagine drawing a line in a bar chart based on the integers in the array - the line divides the chart into 2 portions: each of the elements in the bottom half `<= X` and those in the other half `> X`.

Let cost incurred by elements greater than `X` be `H` and the cost incurred by the rest be `L`.
Let `BOT` represent the lower bound for my guess and `TOP` represent the upper bound for my guess.

Pseudo-code for my logic:

```
WHILE BOT <= TOP:
  DO
    X = (BOT+TOP)/2;
    // Compute H and L based on X
    // ...
    ans = MIN(ans,H+L)
    IF H == L:
      BREAK;
    ELSE IF H > L:
      BOT = X + 1;
    ELSE:
      TOP = X - 1;
  DONE

PRINT ANS
```

Example:

```
1 2 9 5 7 6 3 4 2 2
```

Answer should be 70 because we can choose 6.

Sorting the array:

```
Elements: 1 2 2 2 3 4 5 6 7 9
Cost:     6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 15
```

Hence, 6(8) + 7 + 15 = 70

My actual code is shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <climits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int n;
vector<int> a;
int hi,lo,mid,e;
long long ans,foo,bar;

long long scost(vector<int>::iterator up) {
    long long s = 0;
    vector<int>::iterator beg = a.begin();
    while(beg != up) {
        s += mid;
        beg++;
    }
    return s;
}

long long ecost(vector<int>::iterator up) {
    long long s = 0;
    while(up != a.end()) {
        s += (mid + (mid - *up) * (mid - *up));
        up++;
    }
    return s;
}

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);
    lo = INT_MAX;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> e;
        a.push_back(e);
    }
    sort(a.begin(),a.end());
    lo = a[0], hi = a[n-1];
    ans = LLONG_MAX;
    while(lo <= hi) {
        mid = (hi+lo)/2;
        auto up = upper_bound(a.begin(),a.end(),mid);
        foo = scost(up),bar = ecost(up);
        ans = min(ans,foo+bar);
        if(foo == bar) {
            break;
        } else if(foo < bar) {
            lo = mid + 1;
        } else {
            hi = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    cout << ans << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting wrong answer with this method (it passes the example test case). Even though I feel that my logic might be flawed, I cannot produce any counterexamples. Could anyone please advise me of a better solution?

Comment: This binary search method needs first to prove that `if X2 > X1 then H2 < H1` and `if X2 > X1 then L2 > L1`, etc.

Comment: @Crouching Kitten Yes. Indeed. I didn't come up with a formal proof and I had doubts about its correctness but I still wrote this solution because I couldn't think of a better solution.

Comment: I would try to ask this in the math community (a bit reformulated, more examples, without c++). They might reduce this to a linear programming problem.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2106921/14578, http://stackoverflow.com/q/41774524/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @CrouchingKitten, in the future if you're going to suggest another site, please remind people not to cross-post: you might suggest that they delete the question here before posting it elsewhere.  Thank you!

Comment: @Silicomancer, in the future if you're going to suggest another site, please remind people not to cross-post: you might suggest that they delete the question here before posting it elsewhere.  This got cross-posted on CS.SE where it was quickly closed as inappropriate, for multiple reasons (we don't do code; we don't debug people's code/algorithms; the question didn't meet our guidelines).  Thank you!

Comment: Also note that, instead of cross-posting, you can ask for further clarification by commenting the existing answer.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to get a counterexample is the following.
Consider some example with small numbers, like `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`.
Perhaps the optimal position of `X` with your algorithm is somewhere near the right end of the sequence *(actual answer after running the program: 84)*.
Now increase all values by a large amount, getting, for example, `10001 10002 10003 10004 10005 10006 10007 10008 10009 10010`.
Clearly, now the squares are insignificant compared to the actual values, and your algorithm will claim the optimal position of `X` is near the center of the sequence *(actual answer after running the program: 10085)*.
Still, it should be clear that if solution is `X` for the first example, it is `X + 10000` for the second one.

On a more general note, your solution claims that the two groups' sums have to be as close as possible, but the division into these exact groups is a claim not supported by actual proof.

To actually solve the problem, perhaps prove that the total cost function `f(x)` is [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function), or, in other words, the finite differences `f(x+1)-f(x)` are non-decreasing.
If that is true, you can then use [ternary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search) to find the solution, or binary search over finite differences `f(x+1)-f(x)` instead of the actual `f(x)`.

Comment: I have managed to obtain a convex cost function. But since the finite differences f(x+1)-f(x) are non-decreasing, how do we use ternary search? Ternary search would only work on unimodal functions right?

Comment: @LanceHAOH: The convex condition is enough for ternary search to work. Perhaps some [other source](https://www.google.ru/?#safe=off&q=ternary+search) than Wikipedia would be more clear.

Comment: @LanceHAOH Also, _"I have managed to obtain a convex cost function"_ sounds strange. You have the one and only cost function in the problem already, it is given. Do you perhaps mean you obtained a **proof** of convexity?

Comment: My bad. With some help, I wrote the cost function as a quadratic function in X. A function in the form f(x) = x^2 + O(x) is convex right?

Comment: @LanceHAOH No, `f(x) = x^2 + 1000x` for even x and `f(x) = x^2` for odd x is surely not convex. Our particular f(x) is convex though. Just look at a point x and see how f(x) changes if we change x by +-1. There are two cases: (1) when x is equal to some value in the input array and (2) when it isn't. Or better yet, follow the formulas from math.se incarnation of the question.

Comment: Sorry. I don't quite understand. Based on definition from wikipedia: "In mathematics, a real-valued function defined on an interval is called convex (or convex downward or concave upward) if the line segment between any two points on the graph of the function lies above or on the graph", if we draw a line between any two points on the graph for f(x) where f(x) = x^2 + O(x), won't the line lie on or above the graph?

Comment: @LanceHAOH O(x) is not a function, it is a family of functions. I mentioned one function from this family: 1000x for even x, 0 for odd x; make it piecewise linear between integer x if you insist on continuous domain. Another continuous example is 10 * sin(x); it is in O(1) but O(1) is a subset of O(x). These examples are clearly not convex, and adding x^2 does not make them convex for small x (see [the graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+x%5E2+%2B+10+sin+x)).

Comment: Ok. I understand the explanation for O(x). I read from a math s.e. site that if a function is second differentiable and the second derivative > 0 for all x in the domain of f(x), then that function is convex. The second derivative for x^2 is 2. Why would the x^2 be not convex for odd x?

Comment: @LanceHAOH It is true that the function `x^2` is convex. However, the family of functions `x^2 + O(x)` contains both convex and non-convex functions. So, just saying "our cost function is in that family" does not automatically prove that "our cost function is convex". Our cost function is indeed convex, but not because it belongs to that family of functions.

Comment: Oh. I see. Based on the formula given by math s.e. incarnation of the question, the second derivative will have the linear part, NX become 0. This leaves only an answer of 2 for all values of x. Is this a sufficient condition to prove that our cost function is convex?

Comment: @LanceHAOH Almost. We also need to see that when `X` increases, `k` is also non-decreasing.

Comment: That means that we want the value of x in x^2 would always be non-decreasing right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133771/discussion-between-gassa-and-lancehaoh).